# Move a class name to the next sibling every N seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a list as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li class="highlighted">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Every N seconds, I'd like to move the 'highlighted' class to the next element. When there's no more siblings, go back and start from the beginning.

Can someone help with the jQuery to accomplish this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Will it be on load of the Page or some event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li class="highlighted">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var lis = $("#myList > li"),
        currentHighlight = 0;
        N = 5;//interval in seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
        lis.removeClass('highlighted').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('highlighted');
    }, N * 1000);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QtscF/)**

Comment: Just for the sake of nitpicking: this wouldn't work correctly if the default highlighted item isn't the first one.

Comment: @ssg, that's actually a good point. The initial value of `currentHighlight` needs to be compatible with the initially highlighted LI. A more robust solution would do one of two things; (a) read which LI is initially highlighted and set `currentHighlight` accordingly; (b) set the initial highlight to reflect the hard-coded value of `currentHighlight`. Both are quite trivial to program. Fortunately, the consequences of `currentHighlight` being initially wrong are not disasterous - all will come into synch at first call of the timeout function.

Answer (score 4):

okay, so basically you'll do something like this

```
    function highlight_next_li() {
        var current = jQuery('.highlighted'); // get the current highlighted
        var next = current.next();

        // if no next then we're at the end
        if( !next.length )
            next = current.parent().find('li:first'); // get the first li element in the parent

        next.addClass('highlighted');
        current.removeClass('highlighted');
    }
```

Then you'll want to use setinterval .. setinterval repeats a set function every X milliseconds ..

```
    var myinterval = setInterval( highlight_next_li, 3000 ); // repeat that javascrispt every 3 seconds
```

then when you want to stop the repeating

```
    clearInterval( myinterval );
```

Here's a Pen for you see it in action: http://codepen.io/sagetarian/pen/dpKku

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  var $li = $("li.highlighted"),
      $siblings = $li.siblings().andSelf(),
      next = ($li.index() + 1) % $siblings.length;
  $li.removeClass("highlighted");
  $siblings.eq(next).addClass("highlighted");
}, n * 1000);​ // Run every n seconds
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RM2qc/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/wudhd/

You could take a look at [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) of jquery to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen, lots of different ways to do this... can track the current item in a variable etc

I'm going to show another anyway, I think this way is neat and it'll handle dynamic changes to the list.

Relies on giving the ul an id or class, some way to identify it so it can be targeted, and of course if you are dynamically changing the list will need to make sure after changes there's one highlight still.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(nextSibling, 10000);

        function nextSibling()
        {
            var family = $('#family').children();
            var i = $(family).filter('.highlighted').index();
            $(family[i]).removeClass('highlighted');
            $(family[(i+1)%family.length]).addClass('highlighted');
        }
</script>
<style>
    .highlighted { background: #dddddd; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <ul id="family">
      <li class="highlighted">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```